# If dataTaskPublisher has non-nil data, what is the error type then?

Tags: ios, swift, networking, combine

Before with

`URLSession.shared.dataTask(for request: URLRequest) { data, error, response in ... }`

The `data` field as well as the others could be nil. Now with Combine's

```
URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: urlRequest)
```

The (data, response) tuple is no longer of optional types. I realize that means that we must have it as a URLError that we can catch in the `sink(receiveCompletion: { ... }`, but how can I differentiate between no data and any other error?

Answer (score 2):

Any data provided back by the server will be turned into a "response" object from dataTaskPublisher. The pattern you generally use before dropping that data into an `.assign()` or `.sink()` subscriber depends mostly on your code.

I prefer to use a `tryMap()` operator here, which lets you inspect the response object, and potentially convert things like a 404 response (which isn't a failure state in the Combine pipeline) into a failure.
After that, a common pattern is taking the data and running it into a `.decode()` operator to get a structured object back.

You can then choose how you want to handle the failure - the most common solution there is using `.catch()` to replace the value from the publisher with whatever default value you want to appear.

The core detail of using this might be something like:

```
let remoteDataPublisher = URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: myURL!)
.tryMap { data, response -> Data in 
            guard let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse, 
                httpResponse.statusCode == 200 else { 
                    throw TestFailureCondition.invalidServerResponse 
            }
            return data 
}
.decode(type: PostmanEchoTimeStampCheckResponse.self, decoder: JSONDecoder())
```

this is from the example at https://heckj.github.io/swiftui-notes/#patterns-datataskpublisher-trymap, part of the free online reference [Using Combine](http://gumroad.com/l/usingcombine).

(There's also more detail in there about using catch() to deal with the error from a dataTaskPublisher at https://heckj.github.io/swiftui-notes/#patterns-oneshot-error-handling)

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: urlRequest)
```

give you a publisher with `Output` being a tuple `(Data, URLResponse)` and `Failure` of type `URLError`.

at this stage you could use

```
.mapError()
```

if you wanted to map this value to your own error type or handle it in some way, you can also choose to ignore it and apply:

```
.catch()
```

towards the end of your chain of operations to handle all errors (or just ignore them) in one go.